# Initialization instance

Tags: java, class, oop

[image]
better quality: http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/7802/th3w.png

What i'm doing wrong? Record is class similar to List. 
The goal: i want to save my `Records` in `Storage`. Should I rewrite `Storage`?
Also attached `Record class`:

```
public class Record {
    private int number;
    private int count;
    private Object code;

    public Record(int number, int count, Object code)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.count = count;
        this.code = code;
    }
```

Error: variable "storage" might not have been initialized

I can't initialize this variable, if i not have data for that moment.

Comment: Pasting the code might have been better than linking to a screenshot, it makes things easier to read.

Comment: Also, you are comparing strings in the wrong way. You should use `.equals()` instead of `==`. IntelliJ will help you out with both errors and warnings, just hoover them with the mouse.

Comment: thanks for the comment about the strings I forgot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `storage` variable is just declared but never initialized, thus you get an error when using it. You should at least use:

```
Storage storage = new Storage();
```

Since your `Storage` needs a `Record` variable to be created, a better strategy would be

```
Storage storage = null;
try {
    // ...
    if (storage == null) {
        storage = new Storage(new Record(j, Integer.parseInt(ContentCount), RowContent));
    } else {
        storage.addRecord(j, Integer.parseInt(ContentCount), RowContent));
    }
} catch (...) {
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, this code is based on your current design that leads to problems instead of readability and usability of your `Storage` class. Some recomendations:

- Have a constructor with **no** arguments, so you can avoid the `null` initialization as I do in my current example (note that you pass a `Record` argument but **never** use it =\).
- I **strongly** recommend to change the name of the `List<Record> record` field to something that means it is a `List`. I would recommend at least `recordList`.
- You can create a `Record` and send this object instead of passing the parameters needed in the constructor.

Following these recommendations, your code should look like this:

```
public class Storage {
    List<Record> recordList;
    public Storage() {
        this.recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
    }
    public void addRecord(Record record) {
        recordList.add(record);
    }
}

// previous code ...
Storage storage = new Storage();
try {
    // ...
    Record record = new Record(j, Integer.parseInt(ContentCount), RowContent));
    storage.add(record);
} catch (...) {
    // ...
}
```

Hint: Next time, instead of showing an image of your current code, show a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your actual code.

Comment: Storage want input parameters! I can not do that, before i read the file.

Comment: @Eldar yes, you pass an instance of `Record` in the constructor of `Storage`, but you never use it there (because it is not logical to have that parameter in the first place, that's what `addRecord` is for). Just remove the parameter.

Comment: you are right, it's all because i'm new in OOP and Java too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

initialize `storage` to some value.Like

```
 Storage storage = new Storage();
```

Comment: changed `new Storage;` to `new Storage();`. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

You never initalize `storage`

Also, your Storage constructor does not seem right.

```
Storage(Record newRecord){
   this.record = new ArrayList<Record>();
}
```

You are not using the parameter at all. Either remove it completely(recommended) or use it like:

```
Storage(Record newRecord){
       this.record = new ArrayList<Record>();
       this.record.add(newRecord);
    }
```

Also, I suggest changing the `Storage.record` field name to something like `records` or `recordCollection`. Its easier to read and understand.

Comment: i have special method for this, calling storage.addRecord;
Question not about that. Storage wants initialization parameter.

Comment: Yes, just added it because it seemed out of place to me.

Comment: @Eldar did you read my comment at the other answer? Storage does *not* want an initialization parameter. You put it there, for no reason. Just remove it.

Comment: @Heuster yes, that's covered as recommendation. Check the update on the answer.